# Can the Linux ps command output be filtered by user AND command?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, scripting

I need the pid for a process given its owner and its command. I can filter a process per user with "ps -u xxx" and its command by "ps -C yyy", but when I try "ps -u xxx -C yyy", they are combined using OR logic. I need AND logic. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I find this "OR" logic in ps filters is extremely unuseful and counterintuitive (facepalm).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use pgrep?

```
pgrep -U xxx yyy
```

it returns just the pid (or pids, if more than one process matches).

Comment: @Dave: I cannot reproduce.  `pgrep systemd` shows 9 processes here, `pgrep -U mg systemd` shows 1, `pgrep -a -U mg systemd` shows 1.  Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: I deleted my comment, I was using `ps` by accident not `pgrep` sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Use grep?

```
ps -u xxx | grep yyy | grep -v grep
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `comm` to find PIDs common to both conditions:

```
ps -u xxx | sort > /tmp/ps-uxxx
ps -C yyy | sort > /tmp/ps-Cyyy
comm -1 -2 /tmp/ps-uxxx /tmp/ps-Cyyy
```

Using bash, you can use process substitution to avoid the need for temporary files:

```
comm -1 -2 <(ps -u xxx | sort) <(ps -C yyy | sort)
```

Comment: Works, thank you very much. ... But is there no easier way (without using pgrep, since this is not available in my context)?

Comment: What's not easy about this?

Comment: I know what a `comm` does. But I use it only once a year. It's not intuitive for me. I guess everyone who uses it daily sees this different. The are good reasons why pgrep exists. Unfortunately pgrep is not available in my context .... But it's solved now. The root of the problem is (according to my point of view), that I need to support the very old operation system without pgrep.

Answer (score 0):

A subtle refinement to the `pgrep` approach in the accepted answer (which I also upvoted).

When `yyy` happens to be a substring of another running command e.g. `yyy` is `gnome-shell`, we might get matches for `gnome-shell-calendar-service` as well. Point being, `pgrep` is good, but it doesn't *completely* answer the question (and is the reason I stopped using it).

By comparison, `ps -C gnome-shell` *only* returns matches for the `gnome-shell` process. I also hear @guettli's point about familiarity with commands. Your favorite `sed` or `awk` could be committed to muscle memory:

```
ps -fC gnome-shell | awk '($1=="the_user")'
ps -fC gnome-shell | sed -n '/^the_user\b/p'
```

If you just want the PID like `pgrep`, then `awk` can help:

```
ps -ouser=,pid= -C gnome-shell | awk '($1=="the_user"){print $2}'
```

You don't strictly need to replace `-f` with `-o` in the `ps`, but this post is about *diminishing returns*. If you need precise results, then this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who need to achieve it on the fly (no script), here is a bit easier way.

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -d, -U theUser theCommand)
```